# How to find out who made the last change on particular line using Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I think my title is clear.

[GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/) is a nice plugin for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Are there any similar plugins for [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), which satisfies my requirement?

Comment: I believe that this will solve your problem https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/05/git-questions-how-do-i-see-who-made-a-certain-changes/

Comment: Well, that's great